# jest.mockImplementationOnce() throws error in jest useState

Tags: react-native, jestjs

My React Native 0.70 app is jest 0.29.x useState like below:

it ('shall like', async () => {

```
    const route = {params:{ 
        item:{
            status:'Complete',
            artwork:{
                item_name:"item name", 
                author:"item author", 
                description:"this is description of the artwork", 
                uploader_id:1,  //seller
                escrow_value:10,
                viewer:{
                    seller_name:"seller", 
                    seller_cell:"12345678", 
                    seller_country_code:"86"
                }},
            viewer:{
                buyer_name:"buyer",
                buyer_cell:"987654321",
                buyer_country_code:"86"
            },
        }
    }};
    const navigation = {navigate:jest.fn()};
    const propsVal = {device_id:"a device id"};
    const authVal = {result:"fdkfjdsl;fjdsafkl", myself:{id:1,name:"me"}};  //myself is seller
    const stateVal = {name:"me", alias:"akkus", aka:"aka", storageAccessInfo:"djffke359gkl45j634m55"};
    global._smartContractObj = {wallet:"0xk5m6n5nk67km56m5n6m7k"}; //global = {_smartContractObj:{wallet:"..."}} caused error in jest-circus about undefined 
    const getapi = jest.spyOn(helper, 'getAPIp').mockResolvedValueOnce({
        res:{status:200}
    });
    const setState = jest.fn();  //mock useState
    const statehook = jest.spyOn(React, 'useState').mockImplementationOnce(initState => [initState, setState]); //<<==throws error
    const component = (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <propsContext.Provider value={propsVal}>
            <authContext.Provider value={authVal}>
                <stateContext.Provider value={stateVal}>
                    <Dealdetail route={route} navigation={navigation}/>
                </stateContext.Provider>
            </authContext.Provider>
        </propsContext.Provider>              
    </NavigationContainer>);

    const wrapper = render(component);
    //const setState = jest.fn();    
    const _result = authVal.result;
    const _params = {_device_id:propsVal.device_id, _viewer_id:authVal.myself.id};
    let url = `${GLOBAL.BASE_URL}/api/likes/like?like_viewer_id=${encodeURIComponent(route.params.item.artwork.uploader_id)}`;
    expect(getapi).toHaveBeenCalledWith(url, _result, _params, "GET");
    expect(getapi).not.toHaveBeenCalledWith(`${GLOBAL.BASE_URL}/api/likes/new`, _result, _params, "GET");
    expect(getapi).not.toHaveBeenCalledWith(`${GLOBAL.BASE_URL}/api/likes/remove`, _result, _params, "GET");
})
```

The test code above throws error:

```
● page deal detail › shall like

    Should have a queue. This is likely a bug in React. Please file an issue.
```

The error seems irrelevant and disappears if removing the whole `mockImplementationOnce(initState => [initState, setState])`. How to fix the jest error?

Comment: Don't mock what you don't own. Test the _behaviour_, not the implementation - simulate interactions with the component to change its state, and assert on the visible result of that (or interactions with collaborators).